# Matching two column if they are identical/ similar, ignoring the special characters

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have following table in postgres

```
col1        col2    col3                    col4

NCT04132960 Drug    ds-8201a                ds 8201a
NCT04132961 Drug    ds 8201a                ds 8201a
NCT04132962 Drug    hydrogen sulphate       hydrogen sulphate
NCT04132962 Drug    hydrogen sulphate       hydrogen
NCT04132962 Drug    hydrogen sulphate       sulphate
NCT04132963 Drug    bupropion (wellbutrin)  wellbutrin
NCT04132964 Drug    bupropion (wellbutrin)  bupropion 
NCT04132964 Drug    bupropion (wellbutrin)  bupropione 
NCT04132964 Drug    bupropion (wellbutrin)  bup
NCT04132965 Drug    Galantimine             Galantimine 
NCT04132965 Drug    Galantimine             Galantimin
NCT04132966 Drug    Glucose                     null
```

I am trying to clean above table based on following filters:

```
a. col3 should be similar/ identical to col4
b. length of col4 > 3
c. include row if col4 is null
```

When I run below query I am able to match rows except row1 (which is missed due to special characters) and I am getting false positives. Below is the query and the output I am getting

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE col3 ~* ('\y' || REGEXP_REPLACE(col4, '\+|\-', '\\+', 'g') || 'y') --replace regexp specific sign
and length(col4) > 3
or col4 is null
order by col1
;
```

How can I ignore the hits where col3 != col4 (eg. Galantimin, sulphate), but keeping them if they are same if I ignore the special characters (ds-8201a, ds 8201a) (bupropion (wellbutrin), wellbutrin),  and if the col4 is null.

current output:

```
col1        col2    col3                    col4
NCT04132961 Drug    ds 8201a                ds 8201a
NCT04132962 Drug    hydrogen sulphate       hydrogen sulphate
NCT04132962 Drug    hydrogen sulphate       hydrogen
NCT04132962 Drug    hydrogen sulphate       sulphate
NCT04132963 Drug    bupropion (wellbutrin)  wellbutrin
NCT04132964 Drug    bupropion (wellbutrin)  bupropion 
NCT04132964 Drug    bupropion (wellbutrin)  bupropione 
NCT04132965 Drug    Galantimine             Galantimine 
NCT04132965 Drug    Galantimine             Galantimin
NCT04132966 Drug    Glucose                     null
```

desired output:

```
col1        col2    col3                    col4
NCT04132960 Drug    ds-8201a                ds 8201a
NCT04132961 Drug    ds 8201a                ds 8201a
NCT04132962 Drug    hydrogen sulphate       hydrogen sulphate
NCT04132963 Drug    bupropion (wellbutrin)  wellbutrin
NCT04132964 Drug    bupropion (wellbutrin)  bupropion 
NCT04132965 Drug    Galantimine             Galantimine 
NCT04132966 Drug    Glucose                     null
```

Is it possible to handle this data cleaning in postgres or should I do it programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you 'normalize' BOTH col3 and col4 before doing the comparison like that - replace all non-alphanumeric characters with a hash for example. Then it works as you expect.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE 
    regexp_replace(col3, '[^\w]', '#', 'g') ~* ('\y'||regexp_replace(col4, '[^\w]', '#', 'g')||'\y')
    and length(col4) > 3
    or col4 is null
order by col1;
```

result

```
col1       |col2|col3                  |col4             |
-----------|----|----------------------|-----------------|
NCT04132960|Drug|ds-8201a              |ds 8201a         |
NCT04132961|Drug|ds 8201a              |ds 8201a         |
NCT04132962|Drug|hydrogen sulphate     |hydrogen         |
NCT04132962|Drug|hydrogen sulphate     |sulphate         |
NCT04132962|Drug|hydrogen sulphate     |hydrogen sulphate|
NCT04132963|Drug|bupropion (wellbutrin)|wellbutrin       |
NCT04132964|Drug|bupropion (wellbutrin)|bupropion        |
NCT04132965|Drug|Galantimine           |Galantimine      |
NCT04132966|Drug|Glucose               |                 |
```

Comment: Thanks but the query is still matching to sub-parts of col3. For eg.         
hydrogen sulphate is matching to hydrogen, sulphate, hydrogen sulphate  .. I expect only hydrogen sulphate to be mapped here.

Comment: I see, but this is exactly the case with bupropion and wellbutrin. Could you refine the criteria?